# Redirection In FastAPI to a particular endpoint of frontend

Tags: redirect, next.js, response, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and have a FastAPI backend running on port 8000 and a Nextjs frontend running on port 3000. In the backend I want to send a redirection response so that the frontend goes to `http://localhost:3000/test`, but when I send response as `return RedirectResponse(url='/test')`, the page goes to `http://localhost:8000/test` (backend port) instead of going to `http://localhost:3000/test` (frontend port). Do I have to write the full redirection with port number also as `return RedirectResponse(url='http://localhost:3000/test')`?

Comment: If your backend is an API that you call with fetch(), it cannot redirect the frontend.

Comment: @Evert So to solve it do I have to use the full link `http://localhost:3000/test`? And I am using anchor tag in frontend.

Comment: Your link is going directly to the backend URL? (i.e. to `http://localhost:8000/test`?) How would the backend know that you want to redirect to `localhost:3000` automagically? It's being requested on `localhost:8000`, and a relative redirect response will use the same host (or the one given through `X-Forwarded`-headers if enabled). If you want to redirect to a different URL, use an absolute URL as you've suggested (and have the prefix as a configuration variable stored in your  `.env` file).

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/300). Your frontend is behaving like a SPA, while sending a request to the backend, the API is saying the `a.com/abc` has moved to `a.com/xyz`, and the base URL is carried on because only the  `/xyz` was specified. 
For full redirect, you should use the `FULL URL` but a better pattern is to let the frontend redirect based on its own logic since your frontend and backend are separate, if you are running the frontend and backend on same port in production(or local), this will work.